# Jenkins: Execute a job where the project/workspace is located on other machine (LAN Network)

Tags: jenkins

Having a PC for developing working with `STS/Eclipse` and `Jenkins` both working in the same machine and same time.

Now for **pre-production** testings is mandatory use servers running together such as `ActiveMQ`, `RabbitMQ`, `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`

Due this the PC goes slower, even worst if `SonarQube` and `JMeter` are running.

The solution needed is have in the same LAN network two machines.

- Machine **A**: with IDE just running with some servers running too, `MySQL` and `ActiveMQ`
- Machine **B**: running Jenkins (and optionally `SonarQube` and `JMeter`)

Thus the tools *dedicated* for:

- Continuous Integration (Jenkins)
- Continuous Inspection (SonarQube)
- Measure performance (JMeter)

are running in a dedicated machine, in this case **B**.

Currently when all is based in one machine. The following is used:

[image]

Thus Jenkins is able to work directly with the *workspace*

Therefore how through Jenkins or with a special plugin we can refer to execute a job, to execute a set of `@Test`, where the project (*workspace*) is located in other PC?

- The project itself about all its `@Test` methods should be not aware that is being executed remotely from Jenkins
- Should only exists one Jenkins server working over the network.

What is the best approach to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Use a shared drive on the network from another machine.  You can use as the directory name \\machine_name or map a drive letter. to shared drive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly is not possible yet.

Comment: Would it work on a Network Drive?  It doesn't matter if the Network drive is on a local machine, Disk Server, or another machine (in most cases).  Some applications like SQL Server requires Network Drive to be on same machine as server software.

Comment: I am taking this approach. Thanks for the suggestion.